# Why is my CSS Bottom property aligning the top edge of div to the bottom of the document, instead of bottom edge?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get an image slideshow to sit right on top of my footer, with the bottom edge of the slider sticking to the top edge of the footer. But when I use the position: fixed, bottom: 0 properties, it looks like it is aligning the top edge to the bottom of the page instead. Why would this be?

I have tried Position: fixed, bottom: 0; and it sends the slideshow div down to the bottom of the page (the div actually disappears because it seems to be sticking the top edge instead of the bottom edge).

```
.slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 85px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #0d9196;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

I expected the two divs to be stacked but it is actually just sending the entire slideshow div off the page at the bottom, hidden underneath the footer. Help!

Answer (score 0):

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport

This is the reason when you're giving `bottom:0` to your elements, they are both stacked at the bottom of your page(viewport) overlapping each other.

Refer `position:fixed` on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

If you want them to be stacked, apply
`bottom: 80px(height of your footer)` to your `.slideshow`

```css
.slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 85px;
  background: #ff0000;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #0d9196;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Alternative Solution:

Add a parent to both the `divs` and position them like this:

```css
.slideshow {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="slideshow"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I understand and that should work. I put the bottom padding so that it wouldn't be hidden behind the footer, which is a bit clunky I admit. But the real problem is it's treating the top edge of the slideshow div as the bottom edge and aligning that to the bottom of the viewport (or 85px above it from the padding)...so the actual contents are hanging out of sight past the bottom of the viewport. If that makes sense. Hard to explain lol.

Comment: @KellieJanae ah! I think I got you. I have added an alternative solution. Check that out!